# Product of quotient map ando the identity is quotient map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

The following is an exercise in Tommo Tom Dieck's book "Algebriac Topology"

If $X$ is a topological space, $A$ is a compact subspace of $X$ ans $p:X\to X/A$  is the canonical quotient map then for any topological space $Y$ the product map $p\times id_Y$ is a quotient map.

I need to prove It in order to demonstrate that $\Sigma(Y)$, the reduced suspension, is the same than the smash product of $S^1$ and $Y$.

What I have done is try to prove that if $U$ is a subset such that $(p\times id_Y)^{-1}$ is open, i.e., is in the form $\bigcup_{i\in\alpha}O_i\times B_i$ then $A\subset \bigcup_{i\in\alpha}O_i$, ando knowing that $A$ is compact this can be reduced yo a finite union.

I don't know how to proceed for now on.
It would be very useful if you could give me a hint.

Comment: Use the fact f is a quotient iff for all V, (V is open iff $f^{-1}$(V) is open).

Comment: Thanks William, that is what I am trying yo prove but It not clear for me, because for continuity one of the implication is clear, but the other one not.

Comment: Show each for each U_i x B_i that the  inverse image is open and use the inverse image of a union of sets = the union of the inverse images of each set.

Comment: I first thought of the Whitehead theorem : The product of a quotient map and the identity on a locally compact space is a quotient map, but that's too  restrictive, as we have general spaces here. So if its true it must lie in the simple nature of the quotient map.

Answer (score 3):

Let $U \subset X/A \times Y$ be such that $(p \times id)^{-1} (U)$ is open. We want to show $U$ is also open. For any $(x,y) \in (p \times id)^{-1} (U)$, there is open $U_0 \subset X$ and open $V_0 \subset Y$ such that $(x,y) \in U_0 \times V_0 \subset (p \times id)^{-1} (U)$. If $U_0$ doesn't intersect $A$, then $p(U_0)$ is open in $X /A$. If $U_0$ has an nonempty intersection with $A$, then $A \times \left\lbrace y\right\rbrace$ is contained in $ (p \times id)^{-1} (U)$. By compactness of $A$, there exist open neighborhood $U_1$ containing $A$ and $x$, and open $V_1$ containing $y$ such that $U_1 \times V_1 \subset (p \times id)^{-1}(U)$. $p$ maps $U_1$ to an open set in $X /A$. This shows that $p \times id$ is a quotient map.