# Smash product of X with $S^1$ (Example 0.10 in Hatcher's)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

My first question/confusion is regarding the definition of reduced suspension $\sum X$ and suspension $SX$ of a space $X$.

Usually, we denote the quotient space of $X$ with subspace $A$ identified to a point as $X/A$. I understand that suspension of a space is like a 'double-cone': we take a space $X$ and consider its cone $CX=X\times I/X\times \{0\}$, then define $SX:=CX/X\times \{1\}$. Therefore, $\sum X:=SX/\{x_0\}\times I$. I understand that it is **not** correct to say that $\sum X=\frac{X\times I}{(X\times \{1\})\cup (X\times \{0\})\cup (\{x_0\}\times I)}$ because this would mean that the whole set $(X\times \{1\})\cup (X\times \{0\})\cup (x_0\times I)$ is identified to a point. Is my understanding correct? Thanks.

Now comes my second question/confusion:

This pertains to Example 0.10 of Hatcher's. I am trying to understand and prove the following statement:

'The reduced suspension $ΣX$ is actually the same as the smash product $X ∧ S^1$ since both spaces are the quotient of $X×I$ with $X×∂I ∪\{x_0\}×I$ collapsed to a point.'

How to prove this?

$X∧ S^1:=\frac{X\times S^1}{X\times \{0\}\cup \{x_0\}\times S^1}$

I think I should now use $I/\partial I=S^1$ somehow but I don't understand how to go from here to prove the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It **is** correct to say that $\Sigma X=\frac{X\times I}{(X\times \{1\})\cup (X\times \{0\})\cup (\{x_0\}\times I)},$ i.e. that the whole set $(X\times \{1\})\cup (X\times \{0\})\cup (x_0\times I)$ is identified to a point. This is due to the fact that $\Sigma X=(X\times I)/\mathcal R$ where $\mathcal R$ is the equivalence relation generated by:
   $$(x,0)\mathcal R(x_0,0),\quad(x,1)\mathcal R(x_0,1),\quad(x_0,t)\mathcal R(x_0,0)\qquad(\forall x\in X,\forall t\in I).$$
2. $X\times S^1=(X\times I)/\mathcal S$ where $\mathcal S$ is the equivalence relation generated by:
   $$(x,0)\mathcal S(x,1)\qquad(\forall x\in X).$$
   Therefore, $X∧S^1:=(X\times S^1)/(X\times \{0\}\cup \{x_0\}\times S^1)$ is
   $(X\times I)/\mathcal T$ where $\mathcal T$ is the equivalence relation generated by:
   $$(x,0)\mathcal T(x,1),\quad(x,0)\mathcal T(x_0,0)\mathcal T(x_0,t)\qquad(\forall x\in X,\forall t\in I).$$
   You can easily check that $\mathcal T=\mathcal R.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'm afraid I don't understand 1) why it is correct to say so. Constructing SX requires that one identifies top of the cylinder $X\times I$ to one point and base to the **other**.  So isn't this distinctness lost if we quotient $X\times I$ by the whole set? 2) I don't understand how you get $\mathcal T$. What is the motivation behind it?

Comment: I also don't understand why $X\times S^1=(X\times I)/\mathcal S$ is true.  We only know that $I/\partial I\simeq S^1$, whence we get: $X\times S^1\simeq X\times I/\partial I$. So from here, how do you obtain $X\times S^1=(X\times I)/\mathcal S$? Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: 1) The distinctness dusappears when you re-quotient by $\{x_0\}\times I,$ i.e. when you make all $(x_0,t)$'s equivalent to eachother, including $(x_0,0)$ and $(x_0,1).$ 2) I get $\mathcal T$ without any prior motivation other than identifying $X∧ S^1$ as a quotient of $X\times I.$ It is just the result of your definition of $X∧ S^1$ as a quotient of $X\times S^1$ and my writing the latter as a quotient of $X\times I.$

Comment: 3) If $X\times(A/B)$ (for any spaces $B\subset A$) is the quotient of $X\times A$ when all $b$'s in $B$ are identified to eachother, i.e. when for any fixed $x\in X,$ all $(x,b)$'s such that $b\in B$ are identified to eachother. Whence $\mathcal S.$

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand 3). What is '$(x,0)\mathcal T(x_0,0)\mathcal T(x_0,t)$' in the second line? Can you please explain that? And I also don't understand where $\cal S$ is used.

Comment: $(x,0)\mathcal T(x_0,0)\mathcal T(x_0,t)$ was an abreviation for $(x,0)\mathcal T(x_0,0)$ (i.e. all $(x,0)$'s are equivalent to one point) and $(x_0,0)\mathcal T(x_0,t)$ (i.e. all $(x_0,t)$'s are equivalent to the same point), because $X∧S^1:=(X\times S^1)/(X\times \{0\}\cup \{x_0\}\times S^1)$. And $\mathcal S$ is used to express $X\times S^1$ as a quotient, which makes it contribute to $\mathcal T:$ $\forall x\in X\quad(x,0)\mathcal T(x,1)$ means $\mathcal S\subset\mathcal T.$

Comment: I'm afraid, I still don't understand how you get $\cal T$ and how that helps simplifying the denominator in $X∧ S^1$.

Comment: Take your time. $\mathcal T$ is simply the relation by which you have to quotient $X\times I$ when re-quotienting $X\times S^1=(X\times I)/\mathcal S$ by $(X\times \{0\}\cup \{x_0\}\times S^1).$

Comment: I don't see a reason for $X\times S^1=(X\times I)/\mathcal{S}$ to be true if $X$ is not locally compact.

Comment: @Thorgott What makes you doubt, and how would this hypothesis be relevant? It is true simply by definition of the [quotient topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)).

Comment: I don't follow. Is the topology on $X\times S^1$ not supposed to be the quotient topology? There is an obvious surjective, continuous map $X\times I\rightarrow X\times S^1$ obtained as product of $id_X$ and the quotient map $I\rightarrow S^1$, but taking the product of a quotient map with an identity map does not in general yield another quotient map if $X$ isn't locally compact.

Comment: @Thorgott https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426918 The only thing needed is  that $\{0,1\}\subset I$ is compact. "Taking the product of a quotient map with an identity map does not in general yield another quotient map": yes it does: it suffices that the quotient map was by some compact.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. You never run out of fun technical lemmas to learn from tom Dieck. In any case, I do think this should be remarked upon within the answer, cause it's still not true for more general quotient maps that taking products with arbitrary identity map yields quotient maps, so it's not like that step is a tautology.

Comment: The result is obvious in this particular case. Compacity of $\{0,1\}$ + Dieck's lemma are overkill.

Comment: I think that in 1), you meant to say $\sum X$ instead of $SX$. Is my understanding correct? Thanks. Because with the relation $\cal R$, I think that we should get $\sum X$.

Comment: I think I understand this now. Thank you very much :-).